# Get decimal values from hexadecimal strings

Tags: ballerina-swan-lake

The `decimal:fromString()` function does not accept hexadecimal floating-point literals as arguments, and the conversion results in a runtime error.
Is there any reason for not supporting the conversion from hexadecimal strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hex syntax is used for the exact representation of a radix 2 floating point number, and is not used to represent decimal (radix 10) numbers. That is the reason ballerina doesn't support hex literals for decimal values(See the spec [section 6.5](https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/master/#section_6.5)) and doesn't have a `fromHexString` like in float.